# How to get the number of elements in a Channel<T>?

Tags: c#, .net-core, channel, system.threading.channels

I am planning a subscribers and publishers system where I plan to use Channels. I would like to log the number of elements in each Channel I use so I can adjust the number of publishers/subs based on the bottlenecks in my system.

I started to wrap `Channel`, `ChannelReader` and `ChannelWriter` into my own classes to count the number of writes and reads but this feels like a hack. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Use the source, Luke](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/tree/master/src/System.Threading.Channels/src/System/Threading/Channels). The source tells you that (a) there is no public API to do that, (b) you can use reflection to get the value of the private property `ItemsCountForDebugger` on both bounded and unbounded channels, and (c) this is safe despite no locking in the getter. Of course this is a hack. Whether the reflection hack is better than wrapper class hack is a question of taste. Public API to get the approximate number of elements in a `Channel<T>` [was requested back in 2018](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/26706), and will be added in .NET Core 5.0 (slated for release in November).

UPDATE: in net5.0 and later, `ChannelReader` has a [`Count` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.count). It returns the item count for the `System.Threading.Channels` implementations of a bounded channel and an unbounded channel with multiple readers, but in the implementation of a single-consumer unbounded channel this property throws an exception. My old comment still applies in this case.

Comment: Thanks, this should work. I guess I need to start looking for solutions in the source as well.

Comment: "use the source" is a bad answer in general, even if a solution is in the source. Even more when there is no solution available in the source. People often post good answers which are not obvious by reading the source. (apart from reflection)

Comment: From dotnet 5 onwards you can use the [`Count` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channelreader-1.count)